# Why is my while loop not being checked until it runs all the way through?

Tags: python, json, loops

Why is my while loop not being checked until the end of my for loop? New to python, so I know what's wrong but not how to fix it. I'm pulling from a json dictionary. What I want is to just output while the period is less than 6, but it pulls all of them and then checks the condition.

```
i = 1
while (i < 6): 
    for date in parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:    
        if date['period'] == i:
            fiveday.append(date['low']['celsius']) 
            fiveday.append(date['high']['celsius'])
            time.sleep(.5)
            i = i + 1
```

Comment: it's a loop in a loop. of course it doesn't exit the inner loop. you could break the inner loop if `i >= 6` too

Comment: don't use the while - it's like you said: first the for will run completely until it is iterated again. Inside the for loop check i and break it if the condition is met.

Comment: The increment of i could be written as `i += 1` and seems not to be on the correct loop level. What do you mean by *condition*?

Comment: How can I write it to check outside of the loop or write it so that it only goes through the inner loop while i is less than 6?

Comment: My head just exploded.

Answer (score 1):

Python is not my "mother tongue" , so bear with me:

```
i = 1

for date in parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:    
    if date['period'] == i:
        fiveday.append(date['low']['celsius']) 
        fiveday.append(date['high']['celsius'])
        time.sleep(.5)
        i = i + 1
    if i >= 6:
        break
```

There may be a more elegant solution but I don't really know python. Should do the job, though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `while`-loop. Simply iterate over the JSON dictionary using the built-in function `enumerate`:

```
for i, date in enumerate(parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']):    
    if date['period'] == i:
        fiveday.append(date['low']['celsius']) 
        fiveday.append(date['high']['celsius'])
        time.sleep(.5)
    if i >= 6:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, indentation determines scope. In your code, `i` increments every time the `for` loop runs. All you should have to do to get the code to work properly is to indent your incrementer down a couple levels:

```
i = 1
while i < 6: 
    for date in parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:
        if date['period'] == i:
            fiveday.append(date['low']['celsius']) 
            fiveday.append(date['high']['celsius'])
            time.sleep(.5)
    i += 1
```

The program is still only going to *check* the `while` condition after the `for` loop has run it's course, but it'll only *increment* once per loop, which is likely what the issue was in the first place.

Alternatively, if you're looking to store all of the things with a `period` under 6, you could cut out the `while` loop and change your check in the `if` statement:

```
for date in parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:
    if date['period'] < 6:
        fiveday.append(date['low']['celsius']) 
        fiveday.append(date['high']['celsius'])
        time.sleep(.5)
```